# Adobe Media Encoder render videos with fixed file size

Tags: adobe-media-encoder

I often need to send people the raw material with mail, Whats App or other size-limiting services.

Adobe Media Encoder can limit the file size with Max Bitrate, but if I have a que with 100 videos, I don't want to calculate the max bitrate for every single video.

Is there a way to set a maximum file size for multiple videos so that AME calculates the max bitrate automatically?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think that's possible with AME. You could use a command-line tool like ffmpeg to do it.

Comment: @stib How would do you that exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Well you can select every output option for each file, selecting the first and holding shift, then clicking the last one. That way, you can change the max filesize for each file. For example, when you have a max of 12gb and must encode 173 files, the max file-size must be roughly 12000/173 mb for each one. You'd only have to calculate that once, alternatively, if you don't even want to do that, you could jam all your timelines in a new one, which you could then limit in filesize. Wouldn't recommend that though, as you'd have to slice them after rendering to get seperate files again.

Comment: I don't have a max size for all, but rathee for each single video

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think that Media Encoder can't do it native.
I know, that [After Codecs](https://www.autokroma.com/AfterCodecs/) has function to render with certain filesize. This size won't be certain, but will be very approx. Also you will need to consider correct resolution for your files to leave your videos with enough good quality.

[image: After Codecs set filesize for video]

Also you can export your files from Media Encoder and then reencode with any converter, that support file size limit.
For example ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -fs 10M output.mp4
```

For a lot of files you can create BASH or BATCH script, depends on your OS.

You can read [this article](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#twopass) to understand, how to encode files with two-pass reenconding and reach certain filesize.